# “Acted in the benefit of ” vs. “acted for the benefit of ” vs. “acted to the benefit of ”

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, american-english

I am not sure about [this quote](http://books.google.com/books?id=rS8qbPLCbioC&pg=PA295&lpg=PA295&dq=%22acted+in+the+benefit+of%22&source=bl&ots=QIUTw4quMd&sig=IzbmlUJSex8-8uqU8Xe1_ECyTYg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gOU5ULX7Lu3OigLY34HABA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22acted%20in%20the%20benefit%20of%22&f=false):

> As to whether the president acted **for the benefit of** the majority, 35 percent of the respondents said that he did not, 30 percent that he only partly acted **in the benefit of** the majority.

Shouldn’t it be *to the benefit of* instead of *in the benefit of* ?  And what about *for the benefit of* ?

Comment: It should be "for the benefit of", my guess is that the writer got the two phrases, "**in** *the interest of*" and "**for** *the benefit of*" mixed up.

Comment: Speaking of "for", the first instance in the sentence *is* with that preposition.

Answer (score 3):

Neither *to* nor *in*.

[OED says](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/17694?rskey=6HSflX&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) "Advantage, profit, good. (The ordinary sense.) for the benefit of: for the advantage of, on behalf of."

Answer (score 2):

You can legitimately use either 'for' or 'to' depending on the situation, but 'in' seems universally incorrect.  "For" has a *slight* implication of intent or purpose.  Contrast these two examples:

> ... the Jury found, that the captain was perfectly warranted in the sale, and that he had acted for the benefit of all concerned.
>
> My point, Senator Bankhead, is that the compression acted to the benefit of the warehouse, not to the benefit of the cotton shipper that purchased it.

In the first, the captain was doing what he thought was best for "all concerned", so he was acting *for* their benefit.   In the second, it's just saying that the compression *happened to* benefit the warehouse.  There may or may not have been intent.

Consider the NGram:

[image]

Comment: If you had said "rare" rather than "universally incorrect", I would have upvoted. But it's never a good Idea to use "always", "never" or "universal(ly)" in answers—someone will come up with a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

All three seem to be used quite interchangeably nowadays:

- *"for the benefit of"* 313 mln results on Google
- *"in the benefit of"* 306 mln results on Google
- *"to the benefit of"* 303 mln results on Google

Ngram's take on this is quite different though:

[image: Ngram]

Comment: "For" is correct regardless, as Roaring Fish said, but I question the validity of these results.  They include things not related to the context of the question, such as 'Geographical variations in the benefit of...' or 'entitled to the benefit of...'  which are themselves correct for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think. "benefit" takes polymorphic forms to represent welfare/interest/use depending on context. Please refer below example.

- "for the benefit of" : for the welfare of
- "in the benefit of" : in the interest of
- "to the benefit of" : to the use of